# How to set a callback by binding a class method in C++

Tags: c++, class, stdbind

I have two different classes `A` and `B`.

`B` contains a reference to an instance of `A`, but not vice versa.

I need to bind a `std::function<void()>` contained in `B` with a method declared in class `A`.

Here's the code:

```cpp
class A{
private:
    int id;
public:
    A(int id) : id(id){};
    void display_id(){ std::cout << "id:" << id << std::endl; }
};

class B{
private:
    A *a;
    std::function<void()> f;
public:
    B(A *a): a(a){}
    void set_callback(){
        f = std::bind(a->display_id,this);
    }
    void invoke_callback(){
        f();
    }
};

int main(){
    A a{5};
    B b{&a};
    b.set_callback();
    b.invoke_callback(); //output should be: id 5

    return 0;
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void A::display_id()'
   19 |     f = std::bind(a->display_id,this);
```

As suggested in an answers, I solved the problem by replacing `std::bind` with a lambda function.

```
void B::set_callback(){
f = std::function<void()>([this](){
    this->a->display_id();
});
}
```

But my question is: What is the corresponding syntax with `std::bind`?

Comment: Are you trying to bind `A::display_id` to `a`?  Or to `this`?  I suspect you meant `std::bind( &A::display_id, a );`.

Comment: Since you are having difficulty with `std::bind`, I should add that since C++14, there is practically no reason to use `std::bind` over using a lambda.  People tend to have an easier time with lambda syntax.

Comment: you mean *f = std::bind( &A::display_id, a );* or just *std::bind( &A::display_id, a );*?
For my purpose, by calling *b.invoke_callback()* I should display on console output of display_id of A.

Comment: You never call `set_callback()` so `f` dones't contain a function. Calling it makes the program throw a `bad_function_call` exception

Comment: this is just an extract of all the code, so I miss it, but I'm still having the same problem. I'm updating first post

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are not calling `set_callback()` at all.

Second, you are not calling `std::bind()` correctly.  It would need to look more like this instead:

```cpp
class B{
private:
    A *a;
    std::function<void()> f;
public:
    B(A *a): a(a){}
    void set_callback(){
        f = std::bind(&A::display_id, a);
    }
    void invoke_callback(){
        f();
    }
};

int main(){
    A a{5};
    B b{&a};
    b.set_callback();
    b.invoke_callback();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7BjR7Q)

Alternatively, you can (and should) use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of `std::bind()`:

```cpp
class B{
private:
    A *a;
    std::function<void()> f;
public:
    B(A *a): a(a){}
    void set_callback(){
        f = [this](){ a->display_id(); };
    }
    void invoke_callback(){
        f();
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/2C4qYb)